# Installing oracle 9i in RHEL5 ... error during the process

Tags: oracle, installation, redhat

Currently I am installing oracle 9i in RHEL5, but I have found that during the installation process at 5% completion it throws this error:

> Error in writing to file /path of oracle home/ctx/lib32/libvs_zip.so

I'm using this guide:
https://sites.google.com/site/bantisandy/oracle/oracle-9i-in-rhel5

Has it happened to someone?

Please someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm sorry ... the problem was that the installers were corrupt, just use others and everything went well. Anyway if someone needed it I leave here step by step the installation that worked for me:

http://ivan.kartik.sk/oracle/install_ora9_elinux.html

Thank you very much